# React - How to combine two api response together

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having a problem in combining these two different api responses.

```
const pastData = useSelector(
    (state) => state.transactions.pastData,
  );
const latestData = useSelector(
    (state) => state.transactions.latestData,
  );
```

`pastData` response shape: `{loading: false, data: Array(3)}`

`latestData` response shape: `{loading: false, data: Array(6)}`

I tried to combine them by using this:

`const combinedResponse = {...pastData, ...latestData}`

But when I logged `combinedResponse` it didn't work as expected.

Expected output is to merge data from responses just like this `{loading: false, data: Array(9)}`

Comment: What result are you expecting? If you spread the props from both, given that they have overlapping names, they overwrite each other.

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work as expected?

Comment: Can you show the useSelector function?

Comment: I already updated my comment thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey this is how you can merge both

```
const pastData = useSelector(
    (state) => state.transactions.pastData,
  );
const latestData = useSelector(
    (state) => state.transactions.latestData,
  );


const pastDataArr = pastData?.data ?? []

const latestDataArr = latestData?.data ?? []

const finalData = [...pastDataArr , ...latestDataArr];

const combinedResponse = {
loading:latestDataArr?.loading,
data:finalData
}
```

you can now use combinedResponse .

Answer (score 1):

See these simplest approch:

```js
var callOne = useCallback(async()=>{
    //...do call
    //Return response
},[])

var callTwo = useCallback(async()=>{
    //...do call
    //Return response
},[])

const combineData = (r1,r2) => {
   return {isLoading: r1?.isLoading, data: [...r1?.data || [], ...r2?.data || []]}
}

useEffect(()=>{
    var result = await callOne();
    var result2 = await callTwo();
    //COMBINE LOGIC
    combineData(result, result2);
},[])
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const [{ loading }] = passData || [];

const combinedResponse = {
   loading, 
   data: {...pastData, ...(latestData.data || []) }
};
```

The Initial values can be changed as you choose. They can be empty `[ ]` or `latestData`. Then, just need to combine them.